# find and replace repeating string in database

Tags: php, mysql, string

I've problematic data in some row of my talbe like following string

```
[data attr1='2300.48' attr1='1' attr1='1116.95' attr1='60.75' attr1='9.22' attr1='' attr1='0' attr1='3593.39' attr1='119.05' attr1='25.96' attr1='27.98' attr1='36.32']

[data attr1='2300.48' attr1='1' attr1='1116.95' attr1='60.75' attr1='9.22' attr1='' attr1='0' attr1='3593.39' attr1='119.05' attr1='25.96' attr1='27.98' attr1='36.32']

[data attr1='2300.48' attr1='1' attr1='1116.95' attr1='60.75' attr1='9.22' attr1='' attr1='0' attr1='3593.39' attr1='119.05' attr1='25.96' attr1='27.98' attr1='36.32']

[data attr1='2300.48' attr1='1' attr1='1116.95' attr1='60.75' attr1='9.22' attr1='' attr1='0' attr1='3593.39' attr1='119.05' attr1='25.96' attr1='27.98' attr1='36.32']
```

Now i want to replace them by only one same string like:

```
[data attr1='2300.48' attr1='1' attr1='1116.95' attr1='60.75' attr1='9.22' attr1='' attr1='0' attr1='3593.39' attr1='119.05' attr1='25.96' attr1='27.98' attr1='36.32']
```

Please keep in mind that the value of the `attr` is varying.

-- update --

how its stored in database
the column name is called `content` and the value in this column is

```
the text of the article
 [data.... ]
 [data.... ]
 [data.... ]
```

the datatype of the `content` is `longtext`

Sorry i can't make the proper structure of sql table.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: how is they stored in the database? just a text field?

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651999/mysql-remove-duplicates-from-big-database-quick

Comment: plz provide your table structure

Comment: is all these duplicate strings are separated by "\n" ?

Comment: @user868766 No there is no "\n"

Comment: @PugganSe i've added info. about how data stored in table please review

Comment: humm ok try this one liner $a is your sample data : <?php $k = array_unique(array_filter(explode("\n",$a))); print_r($k); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that made my work.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("SERVER", "root", "root");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($link, "test");
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%nutr-label servingsize%nutr-label servingsize%'");

    if($res){
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $str1 = strrpos($row['post_content'],"[nutr-label servingsize='");
            $sub1 = substr($row['post_content'],$str1);
            $str2 = strrpos($row['post_content'],"']");

            $finalStr = substr($row['post_content'],$str1,$str2);
            $newPostContent = substr($row['post_content'], 0, strpos($row['post_content'],"[nutr-label servingsize='")).$finalStr;
            $up = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content ='".addslashes($newPostContent)."' WHERE ID='".$row['ID']."'");
            $i++;
        }
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to remove duplicate values, depending on other needs. For example:

```
select distinct mycolumn from mytable;
```

Or:

```
select mycolumn from mytable group by mycolumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove/delete duplicate rows you can use

```
DELETE t 
FROM t 
LEFT JOIN t AS t2 ON (t.content = t2.content AND t.id > t2.id) 
WHERE t2.id;
```

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM t;
+----+---------+
| id | content |
+----+---------+
|  1 | abc     |
|  5 | abc123  |
|  9 | abc123  |
| 13 | abc     |
| 17 | abc     |
+----+---------+
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM t;
+----+---------+
| id | content |
+----+---------+
|  1 | abc     |
|  5 | abc123  |
+----+---------+
```