# Removing Duplication using MySQL Update statment

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How to use counter in UPDATE statement. For example, I have some duplicate records in a column as follows:

```
--------------------
      Ref_Number
--------------------
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
```

How to remove the duplication so the result should be

```
--------------------
      Ref_Number
--------------------
108001798914
108001798915
108001798916
108001798917
108001798918
108001798919
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL remove duplicates from big database quick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651999/mysql-remove-duplicates-from-big-database-quick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. don't forget to make a backup of your data before running these:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table LIKE my_table;

ALTER TABLE temp_table ADD UNIQUE (Ref_Number);
ALTER TABLE temp_table CHANGE Ref_Number Ref_Number INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

INSERT INTO temp_table (all,other,fields,except,refnumber,here)
SELECT all,other,fields,except,refnumber,here FROM my_table

TRUNCATE my_table;

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE (Ref_Number);
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE Ref_Number Ref_Number INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

INSERT INTO my_table 
SELECT * FROM temp_table

DROP temp_table;
```

this is the sample [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1ee6/2)

Comment: Sorry, I could not explain my question. I have many columns in the table and I want the duplicate records to be updated with unique ones.
like using MAX(Ref_Number) and adding one to it and then updating and so on.

Comment: I mean that with unique numbers. 
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914
108001798914

with

108001798914
108001798915
108001798916
108001798917
108001798918
108001798919

Comment: you want them to be incremental?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Incrementing and updating

Comment: Looks like it's close to what I'm looking for. Thanks. I now give it a go.

Comment: I don't believe this works.  Here is a simple SQL Fiddle that doesn't work as expected:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c5d4c.  The most obvious reason, though, is that there is no unique constraint on `ref_number`.

Comment: oh right. you need to alter table and give ref_number unique attribute after you truncated my_table. just added relevant query.

Comment: okay now, there were some problems in my version. but i've fixed them all and added sqlfiddle to test it. thanks @GordonLinoff for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The following will get the information needed for a new ref_number -- assuming there are no conflicts with existing ones:

```
select ref_number,
       @rn := if(@refnum = ref_number, @rn + 1, 0) as seqnum,
       @refnum = rev_number
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @refnum := -1) const
order by ref_number;
```

You can put this into an `update` using `join`, assuming you have an `id` column:

```
update table toupdate join
             (select @rn := 0, @refnum := -1, @prev_refnum := -1) const
     set ref_number = ref_number +
                      (case when (@prev_refnum := @refnum) is null then NULL
                            when (@refnum := ref_number) is null then NULL
                            when ref_number := @prev_refnum then @rn := @rn + 1
                            else 0
                       end)
     order by ref_number;
```

This is a rather complicated statement because MySQL does not make it easy to set variables in an `update` statement.  The use of the `case` is simply to set the variables to remember the previous value.  They are executed in order, even though they fail.