# How to delete duplicate rows in my sql database?

Tags: mysql, alter

How can i delete duplicate rows in my database name ( VB)  included 255 tables using ALTER TABLE in PHP my admin ?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1652413/4421474

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add unique index like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (columnname1,columnname2 );
```

This query will drop all the duplicate rows from your table and it will also restrict users to add duplicate rows in future in the table.

Comment: Error
SQL query:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE vb ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (columnname1,columnname2 )

MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - La table 'vb.vb' n'existe pas

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAlAjouri:- 1. Please translate the error in English. 2. You need to mention the column name present in your table not columnname1 and columnname2. These are examples

Comment: *****@p3plcpnl0192 [~]$ mysqldump -u vbok -p --hex-blob --opt --default-character-set=latin1 vbok > new.sql
Enter password:
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `post` at row: 63755
wwwowtjo@p3plcpnl0192 [~]$