# How to delete duplicated record?

Tags: sql

I have SQL table with duplicated record but one filed is different
How can Delete duplicated record which this filed is null ?
and if two pair is null delete one

```
my table is :
id Number No
1 A25 10
2 A24 20
3 A25  
4 C12
5 C12
```

---

```
new table : 
id Number No 
1 A25 10 
2 A24 20 
4 C12
5 C12
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This question has several duplicates [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651999/mysql-remove-duplicates-from-big-database-quick) and [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table). You should research before asking question.

Comment: There are no duplicated rows... Do you mean duplicated values in the column Number? What if several rows with same Number, both with non-null No values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from mytable where id in(
    select t1.id
    from mytable t join mytable t1 on t.number=t1.number and t1.id>t.id
    where (t1.no is null and t.no is not null) or (t1.no is null and t.no is null)
)
```

Comment: Correct, platform-independent and without temporary tables, well done. But is the DISTINCT required?

Comment: i can't use this query , i have one table what is t and t1 ?

Comment: Handi: you need to replace `mytable` (3 times!) with your actual table name. `t`  and `t1` are just aliases. You don't need to change them. ( http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp )
What error do you get?

Comment: Twinkles: No, DISTINCT is actually not required, because we use DELETE statement. But it would be required in case of SELECT statement.

Comment: but when pair is null , not deleted any one !

Comment: sorry not working , i changed t1.number>t.number to t1.number=t.number and deleted many records

Comment: Handi: sorry for a typo. Try now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
select *
into    #temp1
from    My_table 
group by Number
having Count(*)>1

delete  My_table 
from    My_table 
join    #temp1
    on   My_table.Number = #temp1.Number
where    My_table.Number is null
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. solution**

```
delete from emp
    where rowid not in
    (select max(rowid) from emp group by empno);
```

**2. sloution**

```
delete from emp where rowid in
               (
                 select rid from
                  (
                    select rowid rid,
                      row_number() over(partition by empno order by empno) rn
                      from emp
                  )
                where rn > 1
               );
```

**3.solution**

```
delete from emp e1
         where rowid not in
          (select max(rowid) from emp e2
           where e1.empno = e2.empno );
```

**4. solution**

```
 delete from emp where rowid in
            (
             select rid from
                (
                  select rowid rid,
                  dense_rank() over(partition by empno order by rowid
                ) rn
             from emp
            )
 where rn > 1
);
```